# Python 3.8.1 win 10 cmd sys args issue

Tags: python

Does anyone know why I can't send arguments when executing a script?
I have installed python 3.8.1, Windows 10 x64. I have an environment variable (the folder where my scripts are). I can execute the scripts like this:

```
nameScript.py
```

and it works but if I put

```
nameScript.py 1
```

and in this script I use that '1', `sys.argv[1]` give an error: `Index out of bounds`.

If I execute the script like:

```
python D/path_to_script/nameScript.py 1
```

it works.

Comment: I can acces them from anywhere, I don't need to go to the path of the script.

Comment: Thank you, it solved it

Answer (score 1):

your editor configuration is different than default command prompt.May be that is not reading your path and other things.

when executing like

```
nameScript.py 1
```

it understand that nameScript.py is a program and 1 is argument.
hence

```
sys.argv[0] = 1
sys.argv[1] = Error
```

Comment: accpet as answer if it solves your problem

Comment: How can I change the config?

Comment: try to reset setting of your ide,tell me editor name for that. 
Also chagne executing file as python file name. Do not make .py executable and instead run wittython environment

Answer (score 0):

sys.argv is filled with command line arguments. The first one sys.argv[0] is the script name, then sys.argv[1] is the first argument. Like this:

```
python myscript.py arg1 arg2
```

Then sys.argv[0] is 'myscript.py' sys.argv[1] is 'arg1' sys.argv[2] is 'arg2'

I think you need to create an enviroment variable that points to your python/bin folder instead your project/script folder.

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: See the comment by Masklinn.